# How to make listview show images

Tags: vb.net

How i can make my listview show images, What's wrong with my code ?

```
    Dim lines As String() = listaa.Split(",")        
    lines = lines.Where(Function(s) s.Trim() <> String.Empty).ToArray()

    For Each item In lines

    Next

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim imageListSmall As New ImageList()
    Dim imageListLarge As New ImageList()
    imageListSmall.ImageSize = New Size(80, 80)
    imageListLarge.ImageSize = New Size(110, 110)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim item1 As New ListViewItem(line, 1)
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {item1})
        'dsadsadsa


        Dim lool$ = line.IndexOf("watch?v=") + 8
        Dim lengg$ = line.Length - lool

        Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData("http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/" & line.ToString.Substring(lool, lengg).Trim & "/hqdefault.jpg")))
        imageListSmall.Images.Add(line.ToString.Substring(lool, lengg).Trim, tImage)
        imageListSmall.Images.Add(line.ToString.Substring(lool, lengg).Trim, tImage)


        ListView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge
        ListView1.SmallImageList = imageListSmall
    Next


    Me.Controls.Add(ListView1)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Video found", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
```

so, again What's wrong with me code ? why the images dont show up in the listview1 but only the text

```
        ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon
        ListView1.AllowColumnReorder = False
        ListView1.GridLines = False
        ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
```

Answer (score 0):

each ListViewItem you want to display an image needs to have the `ImageKey` or ImageIndex` set to indicate which image in the ImageList pertains to it:

```
  item1.ImageIndex = 1
  ' or
  item1.ImageKey = "Video"
```

You only need to set the ImageList once (your code does it over and over in the loop).

When you are building the ImageList(s) you can assign the key at the same time that you add an image:

```
    imgList.Images.Add("Fruit", My.Resources.Fruit)
    imgList.Images.Add("Veggie", My.Resources.Veggie)

    ' then assign to an item:
    newItem.ImageKey = "Fruit"
```

Since you are parsing this from a web site, you might want to check at the end so see if any images get added.  If you just use an index to start (`Item1.ImageIndex = someVar`) you'll be able to see if any are being fetched into the ImageList.

Comment: so i add 
            item1.ImageKey = line.ToString.Substring(lool, lengg).Trim

at the final, between listview1.sm[...] and next AND nothing happends :<

Comment: well, whatever key you use also needs to have assigned that key to one of the images in the lists.  make sure you assign the same text it to an Imagelist image as you build it.  See Edit